# Move figures around in a document with a simple command

Tags: graphics, floats

During the draft phase of an article, when the text is being developed and things move around a lot, I place all my figures at the end of the document so that I'm not greeted with sudden layout changes. Later, when I'm more comfortable with the text (but still liable to change), I bring the figures upfront one by one.

My question is: Instead of having to lug around the entire

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[...]{...}
    \label{fig:test}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

block to reposition the figure, is it possible to leave them where they are (i.e. towards the end of the document) and "place" them where I want by simply referencing them in some custom way, such as:

```
\placehere{fig:test}
```

which will place the float (defined later in the document) at the current position? This way, I can move the figures around with a single line instead of several.

The resulting document layout would look something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[5]
\placehere{fig:test1}

\section{Dolor}
\lipsum[5]
\placehere{fig:test2}

\section{Final section}
\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[...]{...}
    \label{fig:test1}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[...]{...}
    \label{fig:test2}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `endfloat` package.

Comment: Just make a macro for each figure, e.g., `\newcommand{\figureone}{\begin{figure}...\end{figure}}`. Then use `\figureone` wherever you want the figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following implementation requires that you prepare your figures and tables in a different file, which is anyway better for the application you have in mind.

In the example code the `figure` environments have been typed in a `filecontents` environment. You don't need it, just prepare a file with the same name as your main LaTeX file and extension `.flo`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.flo}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    ABC
    \caption{...}
    \label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    DEF
    \caption{...}
    \label{fig:test2}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.flo}{\setupprefloats}{}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setupprefloats}{%
  \let\figure\relax\let\endfigure\relax
  \let\table\relax\let\endtable\relax
  \prefloat@rename{figure}\prefloat@rename{table}%
}

\newcommand{\prefloat@rename}[1]{%
  \NewEnviron{#1}{%
    \let\label\prefloat@label
    \renewcommand\caption[2][]{####2}%
    \setbox\z@=\vbox{\BODY}
    \toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname prefloat@\theprefloat@label\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\begin{#1}\the\toks@\noexpand\end{#1}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\prefloat@label}[1]{%
  \gdef\theprefloat@label{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\placehere}[1]{%
\expandafter\show\csname prefloat@#1\endcsname
  \@nameuse{prefloat@#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[5]
\placehere{fig:test1}

\section{Dolor}
\lipsum[5]
\placehere{fig:test2}

\section{Final section}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

At `\begin{document}` the file will be read in and the `figure` and `table` environments are temporarily redefined to store their contents in a special command that is later delivered with the `\placehere` command.

Comment: Is it not good practice to have the labels inside the caption? 

I refer to this comment from the LaTeX wiki http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX 

"A label may sometimes pick up the section or list number instead of the figure number. In this case, put the label inside the caption to ensure correct numbering."

Comment: is this code still working? I'm getting

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \prefloat@rename.

Comment: @PatrickT The code was wrong! I fixed it, thanks. Maybe it has to do with the newest version of `environ`. The note in the Wikibook is mysterious: the wrong number is picked up only if `\label` is before `\caption`. While `\label` inside the argument to `\caption` is legal, I find it much better placing it outside (after `\caption`, of course).

Comment: thanks for fixing it! Yes it works as is now. It didn't work with the ``sidewaysfigure`` environment of the ``rotating`` package, I think, any thoughts?

Comment: @PatrickT No. Please, add a new question with an example.

Comment: Done, thanks! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216386/flexible-inclusion-of-floating-environments-from-external-files

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to define your figures (and/or tables) with macros, rather than environments, the `boxhandler` package has figure/table deferral, using the macros `\holdFigures` and `\clearFigures`.

In both approaches, commenting a single line of code changes the figures from appearing inline to being collected at the end of the document.

APPROACH 1:

Using this approach, you just place the figure content in the document inline, using the macro `\bxfigure`.  If `\holdFigures` is active, it will not print out until `\clearFigures` is issued.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\holdFigures%  COMMENT THIS LINE WILL INSERT FIGURES WHERE THEY ARE DEFINED
\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[5]
\bxfigure[ht]{caption\label{fig:test1}}
{\includegraphics[width=1in]{file1}}

\section{Dolor}
\lipsum[5]
\bxfigure[ht]{caption\label{fig:test2}}
{\includegraphics[width=2in]{file2}}

\section{Final section}
\lipsum[5]

\clearFigures
\end{document}
```

Here we have the document with `\holdFigures` active:

[image]

and here we have it with `\holdFigures` commented:

[image]

APPROACH 2:

I sometimes find it more convenient to define all my figures at the beginning of a document and then call them as needed.  With this approach, you leave `\holdFigures` in the preamble for both cases, define your figures all at the beginning of the document, and then use `\nextFigure[]` to place it inline in your document.  However, you can get all the figures collected at the end by redefining `\nextFigure` to nothing, in which case the `\clearFigures` at the document's end takes care of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{boxhandler}
\holdFigures
\renewcommand\nextFigure[1][]{}% COMMENT THIS OUT TO PLACE FIGURES INLINE
\begin{document}
% DEFINE ALL FIGURES AT THE BEGINNING
\bxfigure{caption\label{fig:test1}}
{\includegraphics[width=1in]{file1}}

\bxfigure{caption\label{fig:test2}}
{\includegraphics[width=2in]{file2}}

\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[5]
\nextFigure[ht]

\section{Dolor}
\lipsum[5]
\nextFigure[ht]

\section{Final section}
\lipsum[5]

\clearFigures
\end{document}
```

The two outputs are the same as before, so I don't re-present them here.