# Flexible inclusion of floating environments from external files

Tags: tables, floats, rotating

I'm interested in using the approach described in the following exchange:

[Move figures around in a document with a simple command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118323/move-figures-around-in-a-document-with-a-simple-command/118333?noredirect=1#comment508194_118333)

In a nutshell, the idea is to store labeled figure and table environments in one file and position them in your master tex file by reference to their label, thus making it easier to move figures/tables around and making it easier to make repeated inclusions or to share figures across documents.

The code written by **egreg** and described above works well for figures and tables, but no longer works with the `sidewaysfigure` environment of the `rotating` package. **Question 1: Can the code be adapted to accept a sidewaysfigure?**

To make this question self-contained, I am going to copy **egreg**'s code. I have modified the original code a little to customize it to my tastes.

I store the code in a `.sty` file and call it with `\usepackage{floats}`.

The original code expected the user to store the floats in a file named the same as the master file but with a `.flo` extension. I found I wanted several master documents to use/reuse the floats, so the main change I made to the original code was to allow the user to specify the name of the `.tex` file storing the floats. This is done with the command `\loadfloats{figures}`, where the floats are stored in `figures.tex` in the same directory as the master file.

Comments welcome, naturally. I have two more questions, which I may ask separately if they turn out to be involved.

**Question 2 Can the code be adapted to allow lists?** e.g. `\loadfloats{figures,tables}`, as one may want to organize floating environments by chapter and/or separate figures and tables

**Question 3 Can the same approach can be ported to the `beamer` class and applied to `frames`?**

There are 3 files named *floats-template.tex* (the master file), *floats.sty* (**egreg**'s code renamed and packaged), and *figures.tex* (the floating environments). In addition, an image named *placeholder* with standard extensions is expected in the same directory as everything else.

*floats-template.tex*

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}% \lipsum prints random text
    \usepackage{floats}% provides the \includefloat and \loadfloat commands
    \loadfloat{figures}% stores labeled figure environments

    \usepackage{rotating}% provides \sidewaysfigure environment

    \begin{document}
    \section{Lorem}
    \lipsum[5]
    \includefloat{fig:test1}

    \section{Dolor}
    \lipsum[5]
    \includefloat{fig:test2}

    \section{Final section}
    \lipsum[5]
    \includefloat{fig:test3}

    \end{document}
```

*floats.sty*

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

    \ProvidesPackage{floats}[2014/12/12 custom LaTeX style]

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118323/
    %move-figures-around-in-a-document-with-a-simple-command/

    \RequirePackage{environ}%

    \AtBeginDocument{%
      \begingroup
      \InputIfFileExists{\thefloats.tex}{\setupprefloats}{}%
      \endgroup
    }

    \makeatletter
      \newcommand{\loadfloat}[1]{%
        \newcommand{\thefloats}{#1}%
    }

    \newcommand{\setupprefloats}{%
      \let\figure\relax\let\endfigure\relax
      \let\table\relax\let\endtable\relax
      \prefloat@rename{figure}\prefloat@rename{table}%
    }

    \newcommand{\prefloat@rename}[1]{%
      \NewEnviron{#1}{%
        \let\label\prefloat@label
        \renewcommand\caption[2][]{####2}%
        \setbox\z@=\vbox{\BODY}
        \toks@=\expandafter{\BODY}
        \expandafter\xdef\csname prefloat@\theprefloat@label\endcsname{%
          \noexpand\begin{#1}\the\toks@\noexpand\end{#1}}%
      }%
    }
    \newcommand{\prefloat@label}[1]{%
      \gdef\theprefloat@label{#1}%
    }
    \newcommand{\includefloat}[1]{%
    \expandafter\show\csname prefloat@#1\endcsname
      \@nameuse{prefloat@#1}%
    }
    \makeatother

    \endinput
```

*figures.tex*

```
    % A multi-paragraph \caption[short]{long} without a short caption option produces an error

    \begin{figure}[thbp]
      \centering%
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{placeholder}%
      \caption[test]{\lipsum[2]}
      \label{fig:test1}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[thbp]
      \centering%
      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{placeholder}%
      \caption[test]{\lipsum[2]}
      \label{fig:test2}
    \end{figure}

    % OFFENDING PIECE OF CODE
    %\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    %  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{placeholder}%
    %  \caption[test]{\lipsum[2]}
    %  \label{fig:test3}
    %\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

Comment: I just added an answer to the referenced question.  May or may not apply to your problem.

Comment: The date inside the ``\ProvidesPackage{floats}`` command is tomorrow's date, the 12/12 because I didn't know if I was expected to use the 12/11 or 11/12 style! :-)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thanks, will look into it. To explain my purpose in different words: imagine I have a project resulting in 100 figures and 100 tables updated daily and I write several articles and beamer presentations based on different parts of the projects. I do not want to copy-paste figure/table code that could become outdated, but want to insert them on-the-fly by reference to their label.

Comment: I see.  That's a bit more than `boxhandler` can do at the moment.  However, it may provide a basis that can be modified.  Since I wrote the package, I'll give it some thought.

Comment: I think that you would need a very different approach for `beamer`. `frame` environments do not float. Moreover, `beamer` does all kinds of special parsing and handling to deal with overlay specifications etc. Can you not use `standalone` in that case?

Comment: @cfr, thanks for the tip. I will look into the ``beamer`` class after I get a solution for the ``article`` class, and hopefully learn enough in the process to hack the ``\includeonlyframes`` command that is the closest thing I've seen to my purpose. Will probably ask a separate question later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in the answer I referenced in my comment, I used my `boxhandler` package as a starting point, and modified it by creating the macros `\storeFigure[label]{caption}{content}` and `\recallFigure[htbp]{label}`.

With `boxhandler`, figures (and tables) are created with macros, not environments.  The package provides flexible captioning options.  Disclaimer: clearly, the store and recall options should not be used in conjunction with the package's `\holdFigures` option.

In my MWE, I define three figures in an external file beginning with a 1/2" wide figure with caption "side caption". Then I create a 1" wide figure with "caption1" followed by a 2" wide figure with "caption2".  Then I recall the figures in the MWE in the order "caption2", "caption 1" "side caption", referencing them by their labels.

The MWE has been EDITED to allow the use of `sidewaysfigure` on the final figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{boxhandler, filecontents, rotating}

\begin{filecontents}{myfigures.tex}
% DEFINE ALL FIGURES AT THE BEGINNING
\storeFigure{fig:test3}{side caption}
{\includegraphics[width=0.5in]{testfig}}

\storeFigure{fig:test1}{caption1}
{\includegraphics[width=1in]{file1}}

\storeFigure{fig:test2}{caption2}
{\includegraphics[width=2in]{file2}}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter

\newcommand\storeFigure[3]{\@StoreFigure[#1]{#2}{#3}{\WrapperText}{\wrapper}}

\newcommand\@StoreFigure[5][]{%
  \addtocounter{FigureIndex}{1}%
  \setlength\DeadMargin\FigureDeadMargin%
  \def\FigureBoxLabel{fig\roman{FigureIndex}}%
  \def\FigureCaptionLabel{figcap\roman{FigureIndex}}%
  \def\FigCaptionWidthLabel{figcapwdth\roman{FigureIndex}}%
  \def\FigureWrapper{figwrap\roman{FigureIndex}}%
  \def\WrapperStatus{figwrapstatus\roman{FigureIndex}}%
  \expandafter\SaveCBox\csname\FigureBoxLabel\endcsname{#3}%
  \expandafter\def\csname\FigureCaptionLabel\endcsname{#2\label{#1}}%
  \expandafter\newlength\csname\FigCaptionWidthLabel\endcsname%
  \expandafter\setlength\csname\FigCaptionWidthLabel\endcsname%
                                              \CaptionBoxWidth%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\FigureWrapper\endcsname{#4}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\WrapperStatus\endcsname{#5}%
%% After storing figure, reset wrapper to default value
  \global\def%
   \WrapperText{\noexpand\WrapperTextStyle\WrapperTextDefault}%
  \expandafter\def\csname FigureRefLabel\roman{FigureIndex}\endcsname{#1}%
}

\newcounter{loopfigindex}
\newcommand\recallFigure[2][ht]{%
  \setcounter{loopfigindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{loopfigindex} < \value{FigureIndex}}{%
    \stepcounter{loopfigindex}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\csname FigureRefLabel\roman{loopfigindex}\endcsname}}{%
%%  \FigureBoxLabel:     : figi,    figii,    figiii,    figiv,    etc.
%%  \FigureCaptionLabel  : figcapi, figcapii, figcapiii, figcapiv, etc.
%%  \FigCaptionWidthLabel: figcapwdthi, figcapwdthii, figcapwdthiii,etc.
    \def\FigureBoxLabel{fig\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\FigureCaptionLabel{figcap\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\FigCaptionWidthLabel{figcapwdth\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\FigureWrapper{figwrap\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\WrapperStatus{figwrapstatus\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \ReciteFigure[#1]{\csname\FigureCaptionLabel\endcsname}%
                     {\csname\FigureBoxLabel\endcsname}%
                     {\csname\FigCaptionWidthLabel\endcsname}%
                     {\csname\FigureWrapper\endcsname}%
                     {\csname\WrapperStatus\endcsname}%
  }{}}%
}

\newcommand\recallsidewaysFigure[2][ht]{%
  \setcounter{loopfigindex}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{loopfigindex} < \value{FigureIndex}}{%
    \stepcounter{loopfigindex}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{\csname FigureRefLabel\roman{loopfigindex}\endcsname}}{%
%%  \FigureBoxLabel:     : figi,    figii,    figiii,    figiv,    etc.
%%  \FigureCaptionLabel  : figcapi, figcapii, figcapiii, figcapiv, etc.
%%  \FigCaptionWidthLabel: figcapwdthi, figcapwdthii, figcapwdthiii,etc.
    \def\FigureBoxLabel{fig\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\FigureCaptionLabel{figcap\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\FigCaptionWidthLabel{figcapwdth\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\FigureWrapper{figwrap\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \def\WrapperStatus{figwrapstatus\roman{loopfigindex}}%
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \usebox{\csname\FigureBoxLabel\endcsname}
    \caption{\csname\FigureCaptionLabel\endcsname}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
%    \ReciteFigure[#1]{\csname\FigureCaptionLabel\endcsname}%
%                     {\csname\FigureBoxLabel\endcsname}%
%                     {\csname\FigCaptionWidthLabel\endcsname}%
%                     {\csname\FigureWrapper\endcsname}%
%                     {\csname\WrapperStatus\endcsname}%
  }{}}%
}

\makeatother

\renewcommand\nextFigure[1][]{}% COMMENT THIS OUT TO PLACE FIGURES INLINE
\begin{document}
\input{myfigures.tex}

Figures were created in the order \ref{fig:test1} then \ref{fig:test2}.  That they
show up here as numbers means that the labeling worked.

\section{Lorem}
\lipsum[5]
\recallFigure[ht]{fig:test2}
\lipsum[3]

\section{Dolor}
\lipsum[1]
\recallFigure[ht]{fig:test1}

\section{Final section}
\lipsum[2]

\recallsidewaysFigure{fig:test3}

\lipsum[4-7]

\end{document}
```

### [image]

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll need a bit of time to process it and test it, not least because I'm busy with other things today, but will get back to you asap, hopefully before the weekend. It looks very promising!

Comment: I have played around a little and this is very promising. I've had errors when trying to insert a ``sidewaysfigure`` environment (that was my OP, have you tested with a ``sidewaysfigure``?) and/or with the ``siunitx`` package. Also it doesn't seem to take ``\lipsum[2]`` in the caption (which is not a problem).

Comment: I don't think `boxhandler` will work, as is, with `sidewaysfigure`.  At least it was not taken into account during the package design.  However, one might be able to fudge it, by designing a new command nearly identical with `\recallFigure`, but instead of it calling upon `\ReciteFigure`, one could reconstruct a sidewaysfigure from the variables like: the caption that is in `\csname\FigureCaptionLabel\endcsname` and the figure content that is in `\usebox{\csname\FigureBoxLabel\endcsname}`.

Comment: @PatrickT see prior comment

Comment: @PatrickT For sideways figure, replace the `\ReciteFigure` call with something like `\begin{figure}[#1]
\centering\usebox{\csname\FigureBoxLabel\endcsname}
\caption{\csname\FigureCaptionLabel\endcsname}\end{figure}` and whatever else to make it sideways.

Comment: if I do as you say, it doesn't compile, if I use the code ``\begin{sidewaysfigure}[#1] \centering\usebox{\csname\FigureBoxLabel\endcsname} \caption{\csname\FigureCaptionLabel\endcsname}\end{sidewaysfigure}`` instead, then it works, but all figures are then printed sideways. Perhaps adding a ``sideways`` option in the ``\recallFigure`` command with an ``if statement`` to either use ``\ReciteFigure`` as your original code does or ``\begin{sidewaysfigure}`` if the ``sideways`` option was passed. I'll see if I can manage it with my limited skill set. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT  Please see edit, which implements a very simple use of `sidewaysfigure` into the mix.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that worked! I didn't expect the solution to be so involved, but I guess it was worth it ;-)

Comment: The ``sidewaysfigure`` environment apparently adds a ``\newpage`` at the start, which is not always desirable (as in your MWE, where the sideways figure is surrounded by a lot of white space), but there is a ``hvfloat`` package that I plan to start using instead, it doesn't add a break and is also more flexible, allowing figures to be inserted with non-straight angles, which may useful one day, maybe.

Comment: @PatrickT I used `boxhandler` because it had a deferral capability.  But that locked me into the tedious structure of that package.  One might be able to do it simpler from scratch, by essentially saving each figure content & caption in unique macros identifiable by the given label.  Then, use the label to reconstruct the unique macro names for the content and the caption, inserting them where needed.

Comment: My initial reaction was that saving the caption was a bit of an overkill, but then I realized that it could have some pretty useful applications. For instance, to reveal long captions stepwise over several frames; to have a question/answer type layout... So it's a pretty useful feature to have. :-)